# flask request.files empty even though request.args is not

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, python-requests

I'm trying to upload a file to a flask server from a form. My HTML (I'm using React) is as follows:

```
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="file" id="placesCSV" name="placesCSV"></input>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

But the following code in python:

```
    @app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
    def findRoutes():
      if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.args)
        print(request.files)
```

Prints the filename correctly for `request.args`, but `request.files` is empty. I'm also getting:

## Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I've tried the same with 'GET' instead of 'POST' and I have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the request.method to POST

```
    def findRoutes():
      if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.args)
        print(request.files)
```

Comment: Tried this and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: ```@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])```

Comment: The form method should be post not get this should be fixed within the form jsx element

Comment: I think this is what you mean <form action="/" method="get">. Just tried this. Still same result.

Comment: <form action="/" method="post">

Comment: That's what I have now. Still getting bad request error.

Comment: Sure thing. My current code is reflected in the changes above.